# Retrieving values from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an xml file that has been converted to the json listed below.  I have been trying to figure out how to retrieve -Name and -Value from each of the Attributes with no luck.  I'm guessing I need to create a sub-object that is equal to jsonobj.Media.Attribute[i], but am unable to access -Name or -Value once I do that.  Any suggestions?

```
jsonobj= {
      "Media": {
            "Attribute": [
              {
                "-Name": "Keywords",
                "-Value": "keyword value"
              },
              {
                "-Name": "Title",
                "-Value": "title value"
              },
              {
                "-Name": "Description",
                "-Value": "description value"
              },
              {
                "-Name": "Author",
                "-Value": "author value"
              },
              {
                "-Name": "Copyright",
                "-Value": "copyright value"
              }
            ]
          }
        };
```

Comment: Hint: You can use `['-Name']` to access elements of the object.

Comment: iterate jsonobj.Media.Attribute and use ['-Name'] to retrieve the value.

Comment: I've create a subobject and attempted to access it using subobject[0].Name (returns undefined).  I've tried subobject[0].-Name (throws an error), If I just do a console.debug on subobj, I get Object {-Name: "Keywords", -Value: "keyword value"}.  I can't seem to get anything else from it.

Comment: Definitely, you cannot use subobject[0].-Name to access the object because `-` is an operator. If you execute the code, you get an error. Change it to subobject[0].["-Name"] will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will alert all the values you're looking for:

```
var list = jsonobj.Media.Attribute
for(index in list)
{
    var obj = list[index];
    var name = obj["-Name"];
    var value = obj["-Value"];

    alert(name);
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.  Very clear what is going on once I see the code.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate jsonobj.Media.Attribute and use ['-Name'] to retrieve the value

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonobj.Media.Attribute.length ; i++)
{
 var attr = jsonobj.Media.Attribute[i]
 alert(attr["-Name"]);
 alert(attr["-Value"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `-` in the code, cause it is an operator, and JS will not recognize it as a method.

To solve your problem you can access the properties using other way.

Otherwise your code:
`jsonobj.Media.Attribute[i].-Name`

You can use:
`jsonobj.Media.Attribute[i].["-Name"]`

What is the same from calling, for an example:
`jsonobj.["Media"].Attribute[i].["-Name"]`

Answer (score 0):

It can not identify key Attribute. Says can not read property 'Attribute' of undefined.